# Default Date/Time In Medium Format 28 Jan 2008, 16:30:05 instead of 28/01/2008, 16:30

Tags: datetime, date, formatting

Company would like to display the Date format in SF to show the month as text (e.g. Jan instead of 01).  From the following article this appears to be the a OOB option by setting the users Local to English (United Kingdom) in 'medium' format:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_supported_date_time_format.htm&type=5

However I do not see where the date is displayed in 'medium' format or where/if this can be changed. Any help/ideas would be very appricated.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Exactly where are you wanting to display the Date in Medium format?

Comment: @Moonpie System wide for all Date and Date Time fields on detail pages.

Answer (score 0):

Seems showing date in Medium format having some issue in Salesforce side. Please check with this [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000FmAgQAK). Which is also having work around for this issue.

Please let me know if it helps.